# Сравнение двух кодов в С#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существуют два объекта, которые сталкиваются между собой.

На первом объекте находится главный скрипт.

При столкновении объектов ключ key должен изменять с true на false.

Если это условие реализовать на 1ом главном объекте, то получится так:

```
public class ScriptObject1 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public bool key = true;

   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
   {
      key = false;
   }
}
```

Если это условие реализовать на 2ом второстепенном объекте, то получится так:

```
public class ScriptObject2 : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private GameObject object1;

   private ScriptObect1 object1Script;
   
   private void Start()
   {
      object1Script = object1.GetComponent<ScriptObject1>();
   }

   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
   {
      object1Script.key = false;
   }
```

В чём суть вопроса. Порой на сцене находятся не два объекта, а множество десятков с различными Тэгами.

И чтобы не захламлять и не сравнить куча тэгов между собой в главном скрипте главного объекта, приходится разносить на второстепенные объекты код с главного объекта.

Вопрос: Равнозначны ли данные действия происходящие в двух кодах на нагруженность игры, если эти объекты сталкиваются не один раз, а допустим 100 раз?
Или 1ый код использовать пердпочительней?

Comment: Вы же знаете ответ. Откуда этот вопрос вообще взялся? :)

Comment: @aepot, я уже раньше задавал такой вопрос? :) Я просто пытаюсь оптимизировать свой проект под Андроид, и порой задаю, на первый взгляд, очень простые и странные вопросы, но с другой стороны, очень интересующие меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело даже не в производительности, вы хотите избежать хаоса, а это архитектурный вопрос. В этом плане оба варианта выглядят ужасно, но второй просто ужасный ужас, который даже выглядит как перекошенный костыль. Просто по логике, если триггер это скажем монетка, разве не тупо что "монетка подобрала сама себя".

По тегам вообще не сравнивают, поскольку строковый литерал сам по себе угроза ошибки при вводе или изменении, которую потом трудно искать. Только по строгому наличию компонента/интерфейса.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.TryGetComponent(out FooComponent target))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Нужно явно разделять суп от мух. `OnTriggerEnter2D` вовсе не должен обрабатываться в "главном", как ты его назвал скрипте, привет `Single Responsibility Principle`. Если это подбор монет/валюты/ресурсов, то этим должен занимается компонент `Wallet`(кошелек)/`DropCollector`, если это взаимодействие с окружением типа двери, рычаги, лампы и т.д. это уже другая ответственность, для другого скрипта типа `InteractionEnvironment` и т.д. Категорий объектов будет все равно не 100, а крайне ограниченное количество.

Может быть полезным поделить сбор разных типов, разными классами.

Интерфейс подбираемого обьекта

```
public interface ICollectobleDrop
{
    void PickUp ();
}
```

Интерфейс обработчика подбора объекта, у каждого типа будет свой

```
public interface IDropCollector
{
    bool TryCollect (ICollectobleDrop target);
}
```

Пример с валютой

```
public class CollectableCurrency : MonoBehaviour, ICollectobleDrop 
{
    [SerializeField] private CurrencyType _type;
    [SerializeField] private int _amount;

    public CurrencyType Type => _type;
    public int Amount=> _amount;

    public void PickUp ()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

public class CurrencyCollector : IDropCollector
{
    private readonly Currency _currency;

    public CurrencyCollector (Currency currency)
    {
        _currency = currency;
    }

    public bool TryCollect (ICollectobleDrop target)
    {
        if (target is CollectableCurrency currencyTarget)
        {
            _currency.TopUp(currencyTarget.Type, currencyTarget.Amount);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Пример с предметом инвентаря

```
public class ItemCollector : IDropCollector
{
    private readonly Inventory _inventory;

    public ItemCollector (Inventory inventory)
    {
        _inventory = inventory;
    }

    public bool TryCollect (ICollectobleDrop target)
    {
        if (target is CollectableItem itemTarget)
        {
            _inventory.AddItem(itemTarget.Сontent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Сборщие персонажа

```
public class DropCollector : MonoBehaviour, IDropCollector
{
    private IDropCollector[] _collectors;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _collectors = new IDropCollector[]
        {
            new CurrencyCollector(wallet),
            new ItemCollector(inventory),
            new AmmoCollector(ammunition),
            new RestoreCollector(health, mana),
            new ArtifactCollector(achivments)
        };
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent(out ICollectobleDrop target) && TryCollect(target))
            target.PickUp();
    }

    public bool TryCollect (ICollectobleDrop target)
    {
        foreach (IDropCollector collector in _collectors)
            if (collector.TryCollect(target))
                return true;
        Debug.LogWarning("Unidentified item type "+target.GetType());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: С каждым вашим ответом на мои вопросы, вы всегда учите меня чему-то новому. Спасибо!

Comment: С перегрузкой методов ошибся, без приведения типов она не сработает XD, изменил