# Проблема в реализации полиморфизма Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп, полиморфизм

у меня есть небольшая проблема в реализации полиморфизма. В скрипте игрока, когда он с чем-то пересекается

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out ItemWorld itemWorld))
        {
            itemWorld.AddTo(this);
        }
    }
```

у абстрактного класса ItemWorld вызывается метод AddTo, и есть его конкретная реализация в классе CoinWorld

```
public override void AddTo(PlayerScript player)
{
        player.balance.Add(this);
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

То есть каждый дочерний класс от ItemWorld будет сам выбирать куда ему добавляться, и мне не придётся городить большую цепочку if else. Моя проблема заключается в вопросе является ли эта реализация нормальной, потому что мне кажется, что более уместно было бы привести это к такому виду

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out ItemWorld itemWorld))
        {
            TakeItem(itemWorld);
        }
    }
```

При этом я не хочу, чтобы метод TakeItem был просто обёрткой для уже имеющейся реализации.

Comment: Поработай над неймингом. `CoinWorld.AddTo(PlayerScript )` *мир монет добавляет в скрипт игрока*, так и хочется сказать: **"бросай тяжелые наркотики!"**.

Comment: Что мешает измерить производительность и прожорливость обоих способов?

Comment: @aepot, вопрос *"является ли эта реализация нормальной"* архитектурный, а не производительный.

Comment: п.с. нет не является, дроп сам себя подбирать не должен, с такой логикой из зазеркалья можно с ума сойти, его должен кто-то подобрать. `TakeItem` это инструкция для поднятия, для разных типов дропа она разная, соответственно без некой обертки не обойтись, как в [Сравнение двух кодов в С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1455881/352119), если тебе религия не запрещает. Вариант без, будет обозначать что у всех кто принимает подбираемые предметы есть один и тот-же метод с аргементом дроп, чего быть не должно, инвентарь не знает от дропет, только о предметах, кошелек только о валюте и т.д.